# Warning: Cannot find a valid bootloader location (MBR disk)

Tags: debian-installer, mbr, solus

I'm trying to Install SolusOS, but I keep getting the following error message from the OS Installer:

> "`Warning: Cannot find a valid bootloader location (MBR disk)`"

I followed documentation, which suggested the following:

1. Your system must be booted using UEFI mode, as opposed to a “legacy
   mode”.
2. Secure Boot needs to be disabled.
3. Your disk is required to be
   GPT formatted.

Everything checks out, but I keep getting the aforementioned error.

I excecuted the OS installer via terminal, and there were errors regarding `lvmetad`:

> "`warning: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning`".

I [googled this](https://superuser.com/a/1094795/152045), and I disabled it, like so

> "... /etc/lvm/lvm.conf and set use_lvmetad = 0",

I get passed the original error message, but at the end it says:

> "Install bootloader to None'

I'm not installing, and will wait further response

I really want to install SolusOS, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: MBR = master boot record = first 500 bytes of disk for partition table which is the old (legacy) DOS way.  You need to somehow make the partition table **GPT** either before running the SolusOS install or during when creating the partition layout on the disk.  But the disk has to have a GPT (guid partition table) before the boot loader goes to install during the linux installation process.

Comment: The partition table is GPT. `parted /dev/sda p` display "Partition Table: gpt"

Comment: I excecuted the OS installer via terminal, and there were errors regarding `lvmetad`: "`warning: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning`". I googled this, and I disabled it, like so "/etc/lvm/lvm.conf and set use_lvmetad = 0", I get passed the original error message, but at the end it says: "Install bootloader to None'?

Answer (score 1):

Solus is not based on Debian, it's built from scratch. Thus searching for a Debian installer won't help, we use our own.

Your issue is you're trying to install *to* a disk that's set up with MBR, and I assume you're doing a dual boot or OS replace. This is the only time you'll ever see this error, as the installer will **refuse** (by design) to install a UEFI system onto an MBR disk, to save complications.

Sources:

- I wrote the installer
- Also the project lead.